# Rearranging text file into tabular format

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have two files like this File1

```
Cat01_02.1 LAFP2
Cat01_02.1 NUSP8
Cat01_02.1 SP028
Cat01_02.1 ASP01
Cat02_03.1 LAFP5
Cat02_03.1 NUSP6
Cat02_03.1 SP027
Cat02_03.1 ASP08
```

File2

```
Dog06_04.7 LAFP2
Dog06_04.7 NUSP8
Dog06_04.7 SP028
Dog06_04.7 ASP01
Dog07_06.7 LAFP5
Dog07_06.7 NUSP6
Dog07_06.7 SP027
Dog07_06.7 ASP08
```

and I need to make a table from this file like this

```
Cat01_02.1 Dog06_04.7 LAFP2 NUSP8 SP028 ASP01
Cat02_03.1 Dog07_06.7 LAFP5 NUSP6 SP027 ASP08
```

I was trying with Transpose function but it is not working while handling multiple lines of files

Comment: Can the file have more different patterns like Cat01_03.1, Cat01_04.1, etc?

Comment: Yes It has more different patterns

Comment: Are you basically joining the two files on their second field and then merging all results on the combination of the first fields from each file? If not, could you describe your transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't really clear what the whole problem is, but it looks like you are matching the files in the first column based on keys in the second and then aggregating them again on groups of the keys in the second column. If this is a correct understanding then this may work .....

```
join -j 2 file2 file1 | sort -k 2 | awk '
    BEGIN{getline; k=$1; f=$2" "$3}
        { while (f==$2" "$3){k=k" "$1; next} print f, k; f=$2" "$3; k=$1}
    END{print f, k}'
```

First `join` on the second field and output the other fields as 2nd and 3rd fields

Then `sort` the combined file on the 2nd (and by default the 3rd) fields to group the Cat/Dog matches together.

Finally `awk` through the sorted file aggregating the Cat/Dog matches until you get a change in Cat/Dog combination, outputting the aggregated string of matching keys at each change in Cat/Dog combination and also at the end.

Comment: It should be join -j 2 file2 file1, You misspelled it.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat File1 File2 | awk '{if (a[$2])a[$2]=a[$2]" "$1; else a[$2]=$1;}END{for (i in a) print i "-" a[i];}' | awk -F "-" '{if (a[$2])a[$2]=a[$2]" "$1; else a[$2]=$1;}END{for (i in a) print i " " a[i];}'
```

With the first awk command I group by the second column. And with the second one I group by the dog and cat pattern.

However result is not ordered the same way as your example is. Hope it's still good.

Answer (score 0):

One way(assuming order of output is not important):

```
join -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1 2.1 1.2 file1 file2 | awk '{a[$1 FS $2] = a[$1 FS $2] FS $3;}END{for(i in a ){print i, a[i];}}'
```

Using `join`, the `file1` and `file2` are joined using the 2nd column. Using awk, we accumulate the results using the 1st columns as the key.